# UISlider's editingDidEnd event is not working in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uislider

I want to trigger one method when sliding the UISlider is ended.I used "editingDidEnd"event of UISlider in xib and attached it to a IBAction method but the method is not being called.Can any one please help me how to know when sliding is ended on UISlider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UISlider inherits from UIControl so you should be able to add and action on  "UIControlEventTouchUpInside"

Try something like :

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTouchUpInsideAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: ok this approach triggers my method when touches happens,but i want to know when touches on slider have ended.

Comment: Well a touch up inside is triggered when you lift your finger up while it is still in the bounds of the control, so the problem must be somewhere else : "A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control."

Comment: Btw, you might want to also detect touchUpOutside too -- since that would signal the end of an edit too - sliders don't act like buttons (where touching up outside means you've abandoned the action)

Answer (score 7):

You can attach to the "UIControlEventValueChanged" slider event instead and use the following code in your event handler:

```
  [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(handleValueChanged:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)handleValueChanged:(id)sender event:(id)event {
     UITouch *touchEvent = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; // there's only one touch
     if (touchEvent.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded) { /* place your code here */ }}
```

Comment: It's not what the OP asked.