# EditingDidEnd event not working on UISlider

Tags: swift

I am trying to  detect when the user finishes editing a slider. So far I can detect the event when using the AllTouchEvents argument.

```
    radiusSlider.addTarget(self, action: "test", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllTouchEvents)
```

But in fact what I need is for EditingDidEnd to work. But it does not work. Is that because the slider do not support this type event on iOS9?

```
    radiusSlider.addTarget(self, action: "test", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)
```

I've tried the following post as it sounded very similar but could not make the Obj-C arguments to work on Swift. As Swift apparently do not provide UIControlEventValueChanged as a addTarget event for UISlider.
[UISlider's editingDidEnd event is not working in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855542/uisliders-editingdidend-event-is-not-working-in-ipad)

Answer (score 5):

A `UISlider` sends these `UIControlEvents` events when appropriate:

- `TouchDown`
- `TouchDragInside`
- `TouchDragOutside`
- `ValueChanged`
- `TouchUpInside`
- `TouchUpOutside`
- `TouchDragEnter`
- `TouchDragExit`
- `TouchCancel`

It does not send `EditingDidEnd` or any other editing event. Instead, you should subscribe to all of `TouchUpInside`, `TouchUpOutside`, and `TouchCancel`, as any of those events means the user stopped adjusting the slider.

If the slider's `continuous` property is `true`, then it sends `ValueChanged` every time the drag changes its value. If `continuous` is `false`, it only sends `ValueChanged` at the end.

You can subscribe to `ValueChanged` like this:

```
radiusSlider.addTarget(self, action: "test", forControlEvents: [.ValueChanged])
```

(Swift 2 syntax.)